# MySQL Error: returned OS error 765

Tags: mysql, windows, wamp, innodb, wampserver

Mysql returns error

> [ERROR] InnoDB: File table_name.ibd: 'Windows aio' returned OS error
>   765. Cannot continue operation

I used `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%open%';` to check open file count. It shows 2000.

When this issue happen, mysql shutdown automatically.

Edit: This problem happens sometime but not with same table. Also, tables with size more than 125GB have this issue.

Any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds very like you may have a damaged file.

### ERROR_WAIT_FOR_OPLOCK

```
765 (0x2FD)
An operation is blocked waiting for an oplock.
```

> The cause of Error_wait_for_oplock error code?
>
> A Error_wait_for_oplock error may be because of Windows system data file failure. Broken system entries can be a real risk to the health and wellbeing of your computer system.
>
> There are numerous situations that will cause file errors. An unfinished installation steup, an unfinished uninstall, bad deletion of programs or equipment. It can also be brought about when a personal computer is contaminated with malware or adware or spyware infection or through an incorrect shutdown of the computer system. Any one of the preceeding actions can result in the removal or data corruption of Windows system files. This damaged system file will cause missing or incorrectly linked information and data files essential for the optimal operation of the software.

I would start by restoring that database from you last backup.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Installation done properly. This problem happens sometime but not with same table. Also, tables with size more than 125GB have this issue.